# Knockout JS template attr href binding returning function instead of value

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have a template binding that looks like this:

```
    <div style="display: none;" data-bind="template: { name: 'info-window-template', data: currentPlace() }"></div>

    <script type="text/html" id="info-window-template">
    <div class="infobox">
        <h2 id="placeName">
            <a data-bind="data: name(), attr: { href: website() }"></a>
        </h2>
        <h4 data-bind="data: address()"></h4>
    </div>
    </script>
```

and

```
var places = [
    {
      name: "Austin Pizza Garden",
      address: "6266 Hwy 290 Austin, TX 78735",
      website: 'http://www.austin-pizza-garden.com',
    }...]
```

And a Model:

```
var Place = function(data) {
  this.name = ko.observable(data.name);
  this.address = ko.observable(data.address);
  this.website = ko.observable(data.website);
}
```

and ViewModel:

```
var ViewModel = function() {
  var self = this;
  self.placeList = ko.observableArray([]);
  places.forEach(function(placeItem) {
    self.placeList.push( new Place(placeItem) );
  });
  self.currentPlace = ko.observable( this.placeList()[0] );
```

The output works find for both `name` and `address`, but for `website`, it returns the function instead of the url, so the link doesn't work.

I get this when I run this in the browser:

```
<a href="function d(){if(0&lt;arguments.length)return d.Wa(c,arguments[0])&amp;&amp;(d.X(),c=arguments[0],d.W()),this;a.k.Ob(d);return c}">Austin Pizza Garden</a>
```

Why does knockout return the function instead of the text of the url? Why does it work for `name` and `address` but not for `website`? How can I make it return the text of the url?

If you open the project link you'll see that the first infobox div thats from the html actually works perfectly, but its why it gets dynamically called in the js that it breaks.

Full code [here](https://github.com/andrewcockerham/UdacityFENDP5NeighborhoodMap):

Comment: I don't see any problem, other than bindings. Instead of `text` binding, `data` is used. `<div class="infobox">
        <h2 id="placeName">
            <a data-bind="text: name(), attr: { href: website() }"></a>
        </h2>
        <h4 data-bind="text: address()"></h4>
    </div>`

Comment: Rakesh, tried your suggestion, didnt work, in fact the infobox didnt show at all.

Comment: can you put together a jsfiddle that reproduces the problem? I'm interested in looking into this problem, but I'm not going to pull down your whole github repo

Comment: dperry, I'll try, but for now you can load the site by clicking on the link goo.gl/fqiOhS

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your code works.

```js
var Place = function (data) {
    this.name = ko.observable(data.name);
    this.address = ko.observable(data.address);
    this.website = ko.observable(data.website);
};

var ViewModel = function (places) {
    var self = this;

    self.placeList = ko.observableArray([]);

    places.forEach(function (placeItem) {
        self.placeList.push(new Place(placeItem));
    });

    self.currentPlace = ko.observable(this.placeList()[0]);
};


var places = [{
    name: "Austin Pizza Garden",
    address: "6266 Hwy 290 Austin, TX 78735",
    website: 'http://www.austin-pizza-garden.com'
}];

var vm = new ViewModel(places);

ko.applyBindings(vm);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div data-bind="template: { name: 'info-window-template', data: currentPlace }"></div>

<script type="text/html" id="info-window-template">
  <div class="infobox">
    <h2 id="placeName">
      <a data-bind="text: name, attr: { href: website }"></a>
    </h2>
    <h4 data-bind="text: address"></h4>
  </div>
</script>
```

You might want to use the `text` binding, though. There is no `data` binding. (Hint: If you *did* use the `text` binding in your *real* code, post your *real* code next time, not something you just made up.)

You don't need to use any parentheses, either. Knockout unwraps any observables automatically for you during data binding.

However, if you see `function d(){...` as the value of any data-bound property, then you are looking at an observable erroneously wrapped in an observable. In this case you should check your viewmodel building process to make sure no `y` in any `this.x = ko.observable(y)` is already observable itself.

Comment: You're right. I think maybe the problem was in my `showInfobox` method, where I passed in the place, which was already an observable

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove parentheses

```
    <script type="text/html" id="info-window-template">
<div class="infobox">
    <h2 id="placeName">
        <a data-bind="data: name, attr: { href: website }"></a>
    </h2>
    <h4 data-bind="data: address"></h4>
</div>
</script>
```